# How to show some progress animation in my textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show some progress animation in my textbox. Becoz when i click on save button .Records added to the gridview are inserted in the database which return a unique id. This id i want to display in the textbox. But this process takes some time meanwhile i want to show some progress animation inside the textbox. what is the simplest way that i have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give the progress bar as background image

< input  type="text" style="background-image:url(image path)" />

On clicking the save button just change the background image as the loader image and after getting the unique id change the background image as none and then bind the unique id to textbox